# Syntax question in relation to updating state using setState in a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, setstate

I am trying to update a state based on certain conditions that include values given to specific objects in an array. I have tried various syntax which gave me an error such as `this.setState(this.state.destinations[i].map(destinations=>destinations.visibilityStatus=false))`I know that everything else I have written is working except the setState. In the code below you will find the concerned function where with its current syntax updates visibilityStatus of all objects and not the specific one. how can I write the setState so that it theoretically updates the state this way `this.setState (this.state.destinations.map(destinations=>destinations.visibilityStatus=false))` or another way to write it (which still doesn't work) `this.state.destinations[i].visibilityStatus===false`

here is the current code for the function, if you need more details please do tell but usually, this is enough because it's more a problem of syntax then logic structure. Thanks for your time:

```
updateDestinationsVisibilityStatus=()=>{
      for(var i =0; i<this.state.destinations.length; i++){
          for( var n=0; n<this.state.destinations[i].visibilityTime.length; n++){
          if(this.state.destinations[i].visibilityTime[n].visibility===false && this.state.timerString===this.state.destinations[i].visibilityTime[n].value)
          {  this.setState (this.state.destinations.map(destinations=>destinations.visibilityStatus=false))}

          else if (this.state.destinations[i].visibilityTime[n].visibility===true && this.state.timerString===this.state.destinations[i].visibilityTime[n].value)
          {  this.setState (this.state.destinations.map(destinations=>destinations.visibilityStatus=true))}
          console.log(this.state.destinations[i].visibilityStatus)

      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never call setState on one property more than once per event.
It is async and the state is not changed immediatly. As a rule of thumb you should make sure to pass an [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) if you do call it more than once.

This is save in your case:

```
updateDestinationsVisibilityStatus = () => {
    let dest = this.state.destinations; // use local variable
    for (let i = 0; i < dest.length; i++) {
        for (let n = 0; n < dest[i].visibilityTime.length; n++) {
            if (dest[i].visibilityTime[n].visibility === false && this.state.timerString === dest[i].visibilityTime[n].value) {
                dest[i].visibilityStatus = false; // manipulate that local
            } else if (dest[i].visibilityTime[n].visibility === true && this.state.timerString === dest[i].visibilityTime[n].value) {
                dest[i].visibilityStatus = true;
            }
        }
    }

    this.setState({destinations: dest}); // write back to state
}
```

Comment: Hey, @colburton your syntax proposition is correct thanks for that, there is just something you forgot and its the [i] in front of dest in dest.visibilityStatus. I will edit it for you. I tried using a local variable before but I did not know where to place because I thought that this.setState({destinations:x}) only changed this.state.destinations, I used this.setState(this.state) instead which didnt work. Thanks again

Comment: Just one more thing I have removed the local variable and replaced it by this.state.destinations, that works too for anyone interested unless you want to shorten code

Comment: It works, but it has side effects you should avoid. Never write to this.state directly.